# account kit for VueJs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to login with phone number in my project using Laravel as backend and VueJs as front, and this is my code in the VueJs

index.html

```
  <script src="https://sdk.accountkit.com/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
    <script>
        AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
            AccountKit.init (
                {
                    appId:"904814123054635",
                    state:"{{csrf}}",
                    version:"v1.1",
                    fbAppEventsEnabled:true,
                    debug:true
                }
            );
        };
    </script>
```

loginComponent.vue

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <v-flex sm12 md 12>
        <v-btn @click="smsLogin()">Phone Number</v-btn>
    </v-flex>

     <form id="login_success" @submit.prevent="sendRequest()">                                            
         <input id="csrf" type="hidden" name="csrf" />
         <input id="code" type="hidden" name="code" />
     </form>
  </div>
 </template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
          phoneData: {
             code: '',
             csrf: ''
          }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        loginCallback(response) {
            if (response != null) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response.status === "PARTIALLY_AUTHENTICATED") {
                    this.phoneData.code = response.code;
                    this.phoneData.csrf = response.state;
                    document.getElementById("login_success").submit();
                }
            }
        },

        smsLogin() {
            AccountKit.login(
                'PHONE',
                {},
                this.loginCallback()
            );
        },

        sendRequest() {
            console.log("Process Done");
        }

    }
}
</script>
```

But I get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function
>       at b (sdk.js?hash=2ca333864c9c5d0a85615e6017d1d107:98)
>       at s (sdk.js?hash=2ca333864c9c5d0a85615e6017d1d107:98)
>       at sdk.js?hash=2ca333864c9c5d0a85615e6017d1d107:98
>       at sdk.js?hash=2ca333864c9c5d0a85615e6017d1d107:88
>       at sdk.js?hash=2ca333864c9c5d0a85615e6017d1d107:65

Please anyone have any idea about it? 
Or is here any package for VueJs to use Account Kit

Comment: Could you try an use the non minified version of sdk.js? This should give a better idea of what is going wrong

Comment: I did not used minified version of sdk.js. Can you send me a link of it?